# How to select entire row in a Libreoffice Basic macro?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I'm trying to find out how I could select an entire row in a Calc sheet using the Macro language.

Macro recording is of no help, as it doesn't reveal the secret, even if I have recording on while selecting a whole row! Anybody have ideas?

Comment: Do not use the hotkeys Shift+Space, select the command from the menu **Edit-Select-Select Row** and get the line of code `dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SelectRow", "", 0, Array())`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Can use it for further development. I was just wondering if there was an easier and more straightforward way to select the row, e.g. using some methods related to cell ranges or something, where you could specify row number etc.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about this! Of course I have. If in one line, then you can write it as `ThisComponent.getCurrentController().select(ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName("Sheet1").getRows().getByIndex(19))` and this will highlight line 20 on the sheet named Sheet1. Just download [**this book**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt) - there are code examples for almost all cases. *I myself began to master programming for OpenOffice.org using this book*

Comment: Thanks John, this is really what I need! It's been so confusing and frustrating to hunt information about the multitude of classes, methods, constants and everything. Seems there is no real reference manual as is the case with most languages and frameworks, but the relevant information is scattered here and there, and you need to piece it all together.

Comment: Andrew Pitonyak has written several books - they are all good and all available for download on [**his website**](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php). But I really like this book - use the table of contents to find the chapter that you need right now for this specific task and don’t read everything else, you’ll find time for that later.